# Win32/x86 SEH Bug on EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION?

Tags: winapi

I just experiemnted with Win32 structured exception handling.
I generated a singalling NaN through a 0.0 / 0.0 division.

I wrote the following test-code:

```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <cfloat>
  #include <iostream>

  int main()
  {
    double d1 = 0.0;
    double d2 = 0.0;
    double dx;

    _controlfp( _controlfp( 0, 0 ) & ~_EM_INVALID, _MCW_EM );

    __try
    {
       dx = d1 / d2;
    }
     __except( GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION
              ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH )
    {
      std::cout << "exception caught";
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

I compiled the code both for Win32 x86 and Win32 x64.
For both cases, SSE2-code is genrated.
For x64, the exception is caught properly. But for x86, I get an uncaught exception.

When I change the __except-line to

```
  __except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
```

and compile the code for x86, the exception is caught.

Is this a Windows-bug?

[EDIT1]

I extended my program, here it is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <cfloat>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void PrintSseExceptionMask();
void ClearSseExceptionFlags();

LONG CALLBACK Handler( PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo );

int main()
{
    double d1 = 0.0;
    double d2 = 0.0;
    double dx;

    _controlfp( ~_EM_INVALID & _MCW_EM, _MCW_EM );
    PrintSseExceptionMask();

    AddVectoredExceptionHandler( 0, Handler );

    ClearSseExceptionFlags();
    dx = d1 / d2;

    return 0;
}

void PrintSseExceptionFlags( unsigned mxcsr );

LONG CALLBACK Handler( PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pep )
{
    unsigned mxcsr = _mm_getcsr();

    if( pep->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_FLOAT_INVALID_OPERATION )
        cout << "float invalid operation caught" << endl;
    else if( pep->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_TRAPS )
        cout << "multiple float traps caught" << endl;

    PrintSseExceptionFlags( mxcsr );

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

unsigned const MXCSR_INVALID_OPERATION_FLAG  = 0x0001;
unsigned const MXCSR_DENORMAL_FLAG           = 0x0002;
unsigned const MXCSR_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_FLAG     = 0x0004;
unsigned const MXCSR_OVERFLOW_FLAG           = 0x0008;
unsigned const MXCSR_UNDERFLOW_FLAG          = 0x0010;
unsigned const MXCSR_PRECISION_FLAG          = 0x0020;
unsigned const MXCSR_EXCEPTION_FLAGS         = 0x003F;
unsigned const MXCSR_INVALID_OPERATION_MASK  = 0x0080;
unsigned const MXCSR_DENORMAL_OPERATION_MASK = 0x0100;
unsigned const MXCSR_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_MASK     = 0x0200;
unsigned const MXCSR_OVERFLOW_MASK           = 0x0400;
unsigned const MXCSR_UNDERFLOW_MASK          = 0x0800;
unsigned const MXCSR_PRECISION_MASK          = 0x1000;
unsigned const MXCSR_EXCEPTION_MASK          = 0x1F80;

void PrintSseExceptionFlags( unsigned mxcsr )
{
    unsigned exceptionFlags;
    static const struct
    {
        unsigned  flag;
        char     *pstrFlag;
    } aExceptionFlags[] =
    {
        MXCSR_INVALID_OPERATION_FLAG, "invalid operation flag",
        MXCSR_DENORMAL_FLAG,          "denormal flag",
        MXCSR_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_FLAG,    "divide by zero flag",
        MXCSR_OVERFLOW_FLAG,          "overflow flag",
        MXCSR_UNDERFLOW_FLAG,         "underflow flag",
        MXCSR_PRECISION_FLAG,         "precision flag",
        (unsigned)-1,                 nullptr
    };

    if( !(exceptionFlags = mxcsr & MXCSR_EXCEPTION_FLAGS) )
    {
        cout << "no exception flags set" << endl;
        return;
    }

    for( int i = 0; aExceptionFlags[i].pstrFlag; i++ )
        if( exceptionFlags & aExceptionFlags[i].flag )
            cout << aExceptionFlags[i].pstrFlag << " set" << endl;
}

void PrintSseExceptionMask()
{
    unsigned exceptionMasks;
    static const struct
    {
        unsigned  mask;
        char     *pstrMask;
    } aExceptionMasks[] =
    {
        MXCSR_INVALID_OPERATION_MASK,  "invalid operation", 
        MXCSR_DENORMAL_OPERATION_MASK, "denormal operation", 
        MXCSR_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_MASK,     "divide by zero", 
        MXCSR_OVERFLOW_MASK,           "overflow", 
        MXCSR_UNDERFLOW_MASK,          "underflow", 
        MXCSR_PRECISION_MASK,          "precision", 
        (unsigned)-1,                  nullptr
    };

    if( (exceptionMasks = _mm_getcsr() & MXCSR_EXCEPTION_MASK) == MXCSR_EXCEPTION_MASK )
    {
        cout << "all excpetions masked" << endl;
        return;
    }

    for( int i = 0; aExceptionMasks[i].pstrMask; i++ )
        if( !(exceptionMasks & aExceptionMasks[i].mask) )
            cout << aExceptionMasks[i].pstrMask << " exception enabled" << endl;
}

void ClearSseExceptionFlags()
{
    _mm_setcsr( _mm_getcsr() & ~MXCSR_EXCEPTION_FLAGS );
}
```

When the exception is caught in Handler(), it reports that only the invalid operation flag of the MXCSR is set, and no other flag.
So it seems, that there isn't a different behaviour of the FPU in x86-mode, but there is rather a Windows-bug.

Comment: I've found that when I set /arch:IA32 for the code-generation so that x87-code is generated for FPU-operations, the exception is caught properly.

Comment: The SSE-FPU generates the same exception for the x86 and the x84 code, so in both cases this should be mapped to the same SEH-exception.

Comment: It is quirk of the processor, when it runs in x86 mode then it *also* sets the OE status bit in the MXCSR register.  The OS does not want to choose which one is "better" so it generates STATUS_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_TRAPS.  It is up to you to read the status register back and decide which one you want to catch.

Comment: When I set the FPU to unmask only invalid operations by calling 
"_controlfp( ~_EM_INVALID & _MCW_EM, _MCW_EM )"
there should be only one kind exception exception unmasked and I shouldn't get multiple exceptions.
But in this case I get the same phenomenon on Win32 x86.

Comment: I edited the first posting and added a second program, which shows that you're not right "Hans Passant".

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug rather than the more likely explanation of a deficit of knowledge?

Comment: Windows x86 and Windows x64 should behave identically here because the MXCSR-flags are the same in both cases.